# How can I center my address link when it's inside a <li> inside a <ul>

Tags: css

I have the following:

```
<div class="sbr_bdy" style="background-color: Red;">
  <ul style="list-style-type:none; xmargin: 0 0 0 17px; padding: 0px;">
    <li>
      <a title="abc" href="www.cnn.com" class="btn">XXX</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/77Knb/)

I would like the XXX address link to appear centered horizontally inside the red background of the outer DIV. Now it appears to the right. Any ideas how I could do this? Advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just give the li the following style:

```
<li style="display:block;text-align:center;">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li style="text-align: center;">
  <a title="abc" href="www.cnn.com" class="btn">XXX</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Surround link with center tags.

Answer (score 1):

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xavi3r/QeNKJ/

What you should do is add a `text-align:center;` into your css.

Also when you are nesting elements it is a good idea to call the nested elements before the element you want to style, if you added a style for `a { ... }` that would apply it globally to your whole website.

And try to avoid inline styles; its easier to have them in a stylesheet :)

```
#sbr_bdy ul
{
    list-style-type:none; 
    margin: 0 0 0 17px; 
    padding: 0px;
    text-align:center;
    background:red;
    padding:6px 0;
}
#sbr_bdy ul li a{
    background:#eee;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#333;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px 5px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius:3px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#sbr_bdy ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
    border-color:#888;
    box-shadow:0 0 2px #ccc;
}

#sbr_bdy ul li a:active {
    background: #ddf;
}
```